# Trying to add update in view creation

Tags: mysql, sql, database, h2, database-administration

I have created one view on base table test1 and i have added two columns in it while creation.

```
create or replace force view abc1 as (select A.*,cast(NULL as timestamp) AS new1,cast(NULL as varchar2) AS new2 from test1 A);
```

so after creating view, it has data as follows :

select * from abc1;

```
TT            | TT_C2                 | TT_DAY     | TT_HOURLY     | OC   | SEV      | EXTRACOL | IDENTIFIER | NEW1 | NEW2
1468309423961 | 2016-07-12 07:43:43.0 | 12-07-2016 | 12-07-2016 07 | abc  | Critical | asdf     | 1          | null | null
1468922692865 | 2016-07-19 10:04:52.0 | 19-07-2016 | 19-07-2016 10 | abc  | Critical | asdf     | 1          | null | null
1568308812001 | 2019-09-12 17:20:12.0 | 12-09-2019 | 12-09-2019 17 | abc1 | Major    | asdf     | 1          | null | null
1468308812001 | 2016-07-12 07:33:32.0 | 12-07-2016 | 12-07-2016 07 | abc2 | Minor    | asdf     | 1          | null | null
1468308815972 | 2016-07-12 07:33:35.0 | 12-07-2016 | 12-07-2016 07 | abc  | Critical | asdf     | 1          | null | null
```

now i am trying to update new1 column which is of timestmap datatype but i am not able to update the view because of some limitation..

```
update view abc1 set new1 = DATEADD('SECOND', (TT)/1000), DATE '1970-01-01') WHERE new1 IS NULL;
```

Error coming is ::

```
Syntax error in SQL statement "UPDATE ABC1 SET NEW1 = DATEADD('SECOND', (TT)/1000)[*], DATE '1970-01-01') WHERE NEW1 IS NULL "; expected "[, ::, *, /, %, +, -, ||, ~, !~, NOT, LIKE, REGEXP, IS, IN, BETWEEN, AND, OR, ,"; SQL statement:
update abc1 set new1 = DATEADD('SECOND', (TT)/1000), DATE '1970-01-01') WHERE new1 IS NULL [42001-176]
```

How I can add my update "new1" column query into my view creation so that this will be addressed during view creation only.

This is my base table ::

```
TT            | TT_C2                 | TT_DAY     | TT_HOURLY     | OC   | SEV      | EXTRACOL | IDENTIFIER
1468309423961 | 2016-07-12 07:43:43.0 | 12-07-2016 | 12-07-2016 07 | abc  | Critical | asdf     | 1
1468922692865 | 2016-07-19 10:04:52.0 | 19-07-2016 | 19-07-2016 10 | abc  | Critical | asdf     | 1
1568308812001 | 2019-09-12 17:20:12.0 | 12-09-2019 | 12-09-2019 17 | abc1 | Major    | asdf     | 1
1468308812001 | 2016-07-12 07:33:32.0 | 12-07-2016 | 12-07-2016 07 | abc2 | Minor    | asdf     | 1
1468308815972 | 2016-07-12 07:33:35.0 | 12-07-2016 | 12-07-2016 07 | abc  | Critical | asdf     | 1
```

thanks in advance !

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you should not update view.

As per your requirement, you have to use wrapper for getting columns(i.e. select over select).

```
 create or replace force view abc7 as (select tt,oc,sev, converted_event_time,formatdatetime(converted_event_time,'d-MM-yyyy HH') ,formatdatetime(converted_event_time,'d-MM-yyyy') AS event_time_day from (select tt,oc,sev,DATEADD('SECOND', (tt)/1000, DATE '1970-01-01') AS converted_event_time from test1));
```

Hope you find this answer useful.